# How to set a systemd timer to run monthly but at a certain time

Tags: systemd, services

I have a couple of systemd timers which are run monthly:

```
OnCalendar=monthly
```

However, they will run at the exact same time of day. How can I set them to run monthly at, let's say, 2 am?

Comment: I know this link is for Arch, but it should still apply to what you're trying to accomplish: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers

Comment: Thanks. I've read that many times and use it for reference when I create timers. I am still not able to figure out how to use 'monthly' but be able to specify a time for the timer to go off. All the 'monthly' timers go off at midnight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since **monthly** is shorthand for `*-*-01 00:00:00`, you could do something like this:

```
OnCalendar=*-*-01 02:00:00
```

This will run on the 1st of every month at 2AM. Check out **man systemd.time** for more examples.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that it would something like;

OnCalendar=monthly 02:00:00

I was wrong.